# Writing String and integer to stdout in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell and I want to know how to print string and integer value returned by some function in Haskell as we simply do in C++.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int solve(int a) {
  return a * a;
}

int main() {
  int cases, number;
  cin >> cases;

  for (int cs = 1; cs <= cases; cs++) {
    cin  >> number; 
    cout << "Case " << cs << ": " << solve(number) << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I tried similar in Haskell but no luck and getting error.

```
solve :: Int -> Integer
solve = …

main = do
  n <- readLn
  forM_ [1..n] (\i -> do
    m <- readLn
    printf "Case %d: %d" i (solve m))
```

Comment: You have an unclosed parenthesis.  Instead of using `putStr.printf`, consider using `print`.  Also, please post the error message you're getting.

Comment: @Rufflewind Thanks for your reply. while copying I missed that. even with that(closed parenthesis)I am getting error.

Comment: @Lakshman As Rufflewind says, you should also use `print`. What error are you getting?

Comment: @Rufflewind Here is ideone link of my code also error message.http://ideone.com/BkIxbM , Also can you please help me with similar thing in Haskell as My c++ code does.

Comment: @Lakshman: Please edit the additional information into your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `forM_ [1..n::Int]` to let the compiler know the type you want for `n`. Otherwise there's not enough information for the `readLn` to typecheck.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    n <- readLn
    forM_ [1..n::Int] (\i -> do
        m <- readLn
        printf "Case %d: %d\n" i (solve m))
```

`printf` is not so used in Haskell when you do not need its fancy features (e.g. `%04d` or more complex format strings). A more idiomatic way could be

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    n <- readLn
    forM_ [1..n::Int] (\i -> do
        m <- readLn
        putStrLn $ "Case " ++ show i ++ ": " ++ show (solve m)
```

The function `show` converts almost anything to a string.

Comment: I disagree that using printf is less idiomatic. It is obviously shorter - but more importantly, the "printf language" is ubiquitous, so it is not any less clear to use printf.

Comment: @user2407038 Clearly printf is idiomatic in C. In other languages I do not see format strings used very frequently. You can print everything in C++,Java,Python,Perl,PHP,... without ever knowing what a format string is. I do agree that all these languages have their own variant of `printf`, but IMO it it used only in very special cases.